# Kotlin Regex int range using group name

Tags: android, regex, android-studio, kotlin, java-8

In Android Studio(Kotlin) (must use API info: min 25, target 29), I'm trying to add color to a portion of a string using the regex matches' IntRange.

It worked well until I added the "^((?:(?!any).)*?)" part in the expression to avoid word being colored when the "any" word is located between the beginning and the word... The problem is that the coloring gets applyed from the beginning of the string to the end of the found word while I only want the found word to be colored.

I than figured I could use a group name ("value") to fix this problem but I'm having trouble setuping gradle files or the project settings to prevent the "**UnsupportedOperationException**" exception (message: "**Retrieving groups by name is not supported on this platform.**").

I tried many things after searching the internet but it seems that just using the following gradle directives is not enough to make it work.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72"

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Here's my code:

```
val spanBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(content)

var matches = Regex("^((?:(?!any).)*?)(?<value>(word1|word2))(?![^<]*(?<!-)>)", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
matches.findAll(content).forEach {

  var wordRange = match.groups["value"]!!.range    <-- exception occurs here!

  spanBuilder.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorID)), wordRange .first, wordRange .last + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE )
}

return spanBuilder
```

Do you have any idea about what's missing?

Thank you

Comment: If you can not use the named capturing group, perhaps use a single capturing group `^(?:(?:(?!any).)*?)(word1|word2)(?![^<]*(?<!-)>)` https://regex101.com/r/WG6Xjx/1

Comment: How far can the word be from the start of string? Try `Regex("""(?<!\bany\b.{0,1000})(word1|word2)(?![^<]*(?<!-)>)""", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)` if there can be from  to 1000 chars before the word to colorize.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: That worked! Thanx again :-) You should post your replie as an answer (not just a comment); this way I could upvote you answer so you get credit ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you use has 3 capturing groups, where 1 group is named `value` and you can omit the outer capturing group as well.

You could use a single capturing group instead without using the name.

```
^(?:(?!any).)*?(word1|word2)(?![^<]*(?<!-)>)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSaf2R/1)